# Webpack: cannot reach my imported module

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, webpack

**The problem:**

1. I import a .js module in my entry file.
2. It is included in the bundle.js.
3. It is still undefined and cannot figure out why.

*My webpack config file:*

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    // Entry points for pages:
    signup: './signup.js',
    activate: './activate.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: '[name].page.bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json',
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue',
      }
    ],
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: {
      js: 'babel',
    }
  },
  resolve: {
  alias: {vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'}
  },
};
```

*Signup.js:*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import _ from 'lodash';
import axios from 'axios';

import Signup from './vue-components/page-signup-form.vue';

import UrlFunctions from './js/urlFunctions';


if (typeof UrlFunctions === "undefined") {
  console.log("Still not reachable!");
}
```

Outputs: "Still not reachable"

- Lodash and axios work as expected.
- Vue + Vue Component works.
- UrlFunctions module is seemingly imported into the bundle.js, however it says it is not declared.

*excerpt from bundle.js:*

```
...
var UrlFunctions = exports.UrlFunctions = {
...
```

In the module file it's correctly exported.

I don't have one clue.

I have created a single file like:

```
// sg.js
export var sg = "something";
```

I tried to import that in my entry file, the signup.js and this also wasn't declared! ...

*npm-deps:*

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.20.0",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.9",
  "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
  "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
  "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
  "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
  "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
  "vue-loader": "^10.0.2",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.6",
  "webpack": "^1.14.0"
},
  "dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.15.3",
  "lodash": "^4.17.2",
  "vue": "^2.1.6"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that for some reason when exporting a module:

`export myModule; // nOK`

`export { myModule }; // nOK`

`export default myModule; // OK!`

`module.exports = myModule; // OK!`

- I tried to add `include` the folder for Babel from I am importing the Module from: didn't help.
- Reinstalled node and npm completely, switched to Webpack 2: wasn't the problem.

It's welcome if you have any insight on that.